# Getting error "the trait `std::ops::FnMut<(char,)>` is not implemented for `std::string::String`" for a simple type mismatch

Tags: rust

```
    let mystring = format!("the quick brown {}", "fox...");
    assert!(mystring.ends_with(mystring));
```

Error:

```
the trait `std::ops::FnMut<(char,)>` is not implemented for `std::string::String`
```

Changing `mystring.ends_with(mystring)` to `mystring.ends_with(mystring.as_str())` fixes it.

Why is this error so cryptic?

If I create the string without using format, say:

```
let mystring = String::from_str("The quick brown fox...");
assert!(mystring.ends_with(mystring));
```

The error is much more understandable:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `ends_with` found for type
`std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::string::ParseError>`
in the current scope
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's more to that error:

```
| assert!(mystring.ends_with(mystring));
|                  ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::ops::FnMut<(char,)>` is not implemented for `std::string::String`
|
= note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::str::pattern::Pattern<'_>` for `std::string::String`
```

critically

> note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::str::pattern::Pattern<'_>` for `std::string::String`

[`String`'s `.ends_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.ends_with) accepts any value that implements the `Pattern` trait as its search pattern, and `String` does not implement that trait.

If you look at [the documentation for `Pattern`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html), it includes

```
impl<'a, 'b> Pattern<'a> for &'b String
```

so your snippet works fine if you change

```
assert!(mystring.ends_with(mystring));
```

to

```
assert!(mystring.ends_with(&mystring));
```

It also makes sense because otherwise you'd be trying to pass *ownership* of `mystring` to the `ends_with` function, which doesn't seem right.

As for the specific error you were seeing, `Pattern`'s trait definition also includes

```
impl<'a, F> Pattern<'a> for F 
where
    F: FnMut(char) -> bool,
```

which generically says functions accepting a char and returning a boolean count as patterns, leading to the message saying `String` does not match that trait implementation.